# SSIS: problem with Merge join/Conditional split

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a problem with a conditional split.

I am simply taking the table name, column name, datatype and max length columns from `information_schema.columns` on both my Production and Test servers and comparing the data structures, looking for missing columns, different datatypes and data lengths.

I order each of the data sources by tablename and columnname for the merge join, and then check for differences in my conditional split. The records are then written to a recordset for use within a foreach loop in the control flow.

I tried doing it with one conditional split, checking for missing columns in test, different datatypes, lengths, but that didn't seem to work correctly because it was getting records rejected that are identical.

formula was:

```
(ISNULL(CNP) ? " " : TRIM(CNP)) != (ISNULL(CNT) ? " " : TRIM(CNT)) ||
(ISNULL(DTP) ? " " : TRIM(DTP)) != (ISNULL(DTT) ? " " : TRIM(DTT)) ||
(ISNULL(MLP) ? 0 : MLP) > (ISNULL(MLT) ? 0 : MLT)
```

I have since modified the flow so it now has cascading conditional splits with the same result.

I could just create another sql execute task and delete the records that are truly matched from the mismatched recordset, but that's not a solution I'm ok with.  What I am missing here?

Comment: How about a source from PROD that you run through a lookup based on TEST and send unmatched for review?

Comment: Thats an interesting approach - that may be what I have to go with, but I would still like to understand why I am getting incorrect results.  Logically, my approach works...  Thanks Keith!  now I have a plan B at least  :)

Comment: What @KeithL said^

Comment: So you split the single `Conditional Split` task into three separate tasks, each checking a different condition of your formula? Which condition is failing for the "identical" records?

Comment: Any reason you are not using _schema compare_, which comes with SQL Server Data Tools (free), and can generate change scripts.